# I Can't Figure Out Why I'm Getting These Errors

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

Errors:

> ./themezip: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>
> ./themezip: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file

My Code:

```
cat ~/scripts/script-files/repos.txt | xargs -I % sh -c git clone %' && ls
ls -d ~/themes/* > ~/scripts/script-files/dirs
lines=$(wc --lines ~/scripts/script-files/dirs)
sed s/.$// ~/scripts/script-files/dirs > ~/scripts/script-files/dirs1
paste ~/scripts/script-files/dirs1 ~/scripts/script-files/dirs > ~/scripts/script-files/dirs2
cat ~/scripts/script-files/dirs1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'zip -r -q ~/themes/% ~/themes/%/'
cat ~/scripts/script-files/dirs1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'rm -r ~/themes/%/'
rm ~/scripts/script-files/dirs*
```

Comment: Is there a quote missing on the first line?

Comment: `xargs` passes arguments as is. No escaping happens.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

The message should be rather clear: you are missing a `'`. And at the end of the file, you have not closed the last quotes, so the End Of File is a syntax error.

Finding the place where you missed a quote is sometimes tricky. [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) can help you find the place where it probably went wrong. Most Linux distributions also have a package `shellcheck`, which does basically the same.

Shellcheck will give some more hints, like the useless use of `cat` and the fact that `lines` is never used.

Personally, I would also put the `sed` pattern in single quotes, even though shellcheck does not mention it.

And, as @user2182349 stated in the comments, the quote is missing at the first line.